# The type org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

[Config build path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dITTh.png)    package spring.java.config;

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import spring.java.domail.BlogPost;
import spring.java.domail.DataSource;
import spring.java.services.BlogpostService;

public class MainApplication {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);
        BlogpostService blogPostService = applicationContext.getBean(BlogpostService.class);
        // BlogpostService blogPostService =(BlogpostService)
        // appContext.getBean("blogpostSrervice");

        BlogPost post = new BlogPost();
        post.setContent("Hello Sajan");
        post.setDraft(true);
        post.setId(10);
        post.setPublisgDate(new Date());
        post.setTitle("Blog Post Title");
        blogPostService.savePost(post);

        DataSource dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);

        LOGGER.debug("dataSource: url " + dataSource.getUrl());
        LOGGER.debug("dataSource: username " + dataSource.getUsername());
        LOGGER.debug("dataSource: password " + dataSource.getPassword());

        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).close();
    }

}
```

Got Error while Running Application.
I also Attach Screen Shorts below[Click Here Fore Scrren Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yrN5.png)
Give me Solution for this Error.
I face this Error while i m transfer my project to another computer.

Comment: After moved to another pc, have you update the Maven update project via eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I have update it. Here is maven Screen Shoet  [http://i.stack.imgur.com/dITTh.png]

Comment: could you clean the project and build again?

Comment: Already Deon clean and built project.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can solve it by click "Config build path" and config build path for the project, this only works on this computer. You need to config it when move to another computer.
2. You can add dependency to pom.xml, make maven to manage dependency for you. This will work all the time.

   ```
   <dependencies>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: "You need to config it when move to another computer. " --> Steps for Configure Buid Project Path?

Comment: Just click "Config build path", in the pop up window, you can add the jar which includes the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.class.

Comment: All jars are already added to "Config build path" and there is no any error in "Config build path".since i m using porm.xml it will automatically added all jars to "Config build path".

Comment: can you see the jar file in Maven Dependencies folder?

Comment: Try to delete target folder and spring-core.jar located in maven repository and use maven to build package.

Answer (score 0):

Close Eclipse  -->
Go to C:\Users\sajan\m2\repository and delete all folders and files then again update the Maven  and clean it.